# string[i:length] giving memory error

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
def suffix(stng):
    list = []
    length = len(stng)
    for i in range(length):
         x = stng[i:length]   ## This gives a Memory Error..See below
         list.append(x)
    return list
```

This piece of code is a part of my solution of a problem on interviewstreet.com but when i submit it i get a Memory error...i want to know how to correct it?

This is the traceback:

```
Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/run-1342184337-542152202/solution.py", line 35, in
listofsuffix=suffix(var)
File "/run-1342184337-542152202/solution.py", line 13, in suffix
x=stng[i:length]
MemoryError
```

Comment: I would advise against using `list` as a variable name.  It's a bad habit to get into.

Comment: What strings are you passing in? I don't get a memory error if I pass in a string of 3000 characters.

Comment: @NedBatchelder I don't know how they check the solutions but testcase was 5 or 6 characters long.

Comment: ok i don't get a memory error on my machine...i get this error when i submit the solution the site...
Thanks about the list suggestion..

Comment: You may also want to use `xrange()` since you are using v2.7 in place of `range()` .. the former is less "memory hungry"

Comment: okay converted range to xrange...any more suggestions?

Comment: Remember to add spaces between the assign operator `=` as PEP8 recommends, it's a lot more legible. Gonna edit it.

Comment: @Dhiraj -- On the site, they probably monitor your process and put pretty strict limits on how much memory it can consume (they are running completely untrusted code).  Your algorithm is using `sum(i for i in range(N)+N*string_overhead` bytes of memory plus the interpreter overhead, plus whatever memory you've got sitting around for other things -- which could be a decent amount for a decent sized string.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A `MemoryError` means you have consumed all your RAM.  You are creating a list containing all trailing parts of an original string.  If your original string is too long, you will consume a lot of memory.

One possibility is to use a generator to produce the suffixes one at a time instead of creating a list of all of them:

```
def suffixes(stng):
    for i in xrange(len(stng)):
         yield stng[i:]
```

If the caller of `suffixes` simply iterates over the result, you don't even have to change the caller.  If you truly needed an explicit list, then you'll need a different solution.

Comment: Argh, I was just writing this as an answer :)

Comment: One has to be pretty quick to trump the Ned.

Comment: "then you'll need a different solution" -- Yeah.  Get more RAM. ;)

Comment: You don't get to 78k being slow on the trigger, @msw.

Comment: @mgilson: Cute quip, but if you're running a 32-bit Python on a modern machine, most likely Python is already not able to grab all the memory on your system. Just adding more would not help (but switching to a 64-bit Python might).

Comment: I'd not heard of the named site to which this was "submitted", but it is interesting to note that it is limited to 256MB of core https://www.interviewstreet.com/recruit/challenges/faq/view

Comment: The problem has to be submitted on a site so can't add more RAM... i need a workaround

Comment: You say "I need to return a list" which means you don't understand the problem since (presumably) it can be solved within the constraints given. You probably need to re-read and re-think your solution. You've given us too little information to help any further.

Comment: @Dhiraj: you really probably don't need to return a list.  You're going to have to take a step back and think about the whole problem.

Answer (score 0):

"I need to return a list" -- This is highly unlikely.  You just need to return an object which looks enough like a list to make it work.

```
class FakeList(object):
    def __init__(self,strng):
        self.string=strng
        self._idx=0
    def __getitem__(self,i):
        return self.strng[:i]
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.string)
    def __iter__(self):
        return self
    def __contains__(self,other):
        return other in self.string
    def next(self):
        if(self._idx<len(self)):
           self._idx+=1
           return self[self._idx-1]
        else:
           raise StopIteration


a=FakeList("My String")
print a[3]
print a[4]
for i in a:
    print i
```

This creates an object which you can access randomly and iterate over like a list.  It also will allow you to call `len(my_fake_list)`.  It doesn't support slicing, and a myriad of other methods `pop`, `append`, `extend` ...  Which of those you need to add depends on which ones you use.